# SQL Server : Split a single column value comma seperated to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Now I am new to SQL Server and trying to split a column value which is separated by comma and I want each data to have a separate column.

```
2270,2290,2234,2245,2256
```

I want the result to be like this :

```
| Split column |
     2270
     2290
     2234
```

Any ideas will be appreciated as I am way out of depth here? I have `String_split` and set the compatibility to 140 as I am using SQL Server 2017. But all I get is

```
  2270,2290,2234
  2270,2290,2234
  2270,2290,2234
```

This is the query in which the output will look the way I have posted in the question, which needs to be split:

```
SELECT ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries 
FROM [AnimalProductsCoSD].[CoSD].[ERSBusinessLogic]
WHERE
    ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID = 7493
    AND ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue = 'all months'
    AND ERSBusinessLogic_Type = 'HS10 aggregation';
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/22120 . . . `string_split()` works.

Comment: Post the SQL you've tried, if it's not working.

Comment: SELECT ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries
  FROM [AnimalProductsCoSD].[CoSD].[ERSBusinessLogic]
    
  where ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID = 7493
  and ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue = 'all months'
  and ERSBusinessLogic_Type = 'HS10 aggregation' This is the query in which the ouput will look the way I have posted in the question, this output needs to be split

Comment: And what is the query you actually ran that produced those 3 duplicate rows?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem, because `split_string()` doesn't keep the order of the results.  Arrgggh!  This is already a feature request to Microsoft.

Your string looks pretty canonical in its format.  If so, you can just use `substring()`:

```
SELECT LEFT(ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries, 4) as str1,
       SUBSTRING(ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries, 5, 4) as str2,
       RIGHT(ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries, 4) as str3
FROM [AnimalProductsCoSD].[CoSD].[ERSBusinessLogic]
WHERE ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID = 7493 AND
      ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue = 'all months' AND
      ERSBusinessLogic_Type = 'HS10 aggregation';
```

If the ordering doesn't matter, you can use `split_string()`:

```
SELECT ss.*
FROM [AnimalProductsCoSD].[CoSD].[ERSBusinessLogic] ebl OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN val END) as str1,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN val END) as str2
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN val END) as str3
      FROM (SELECT ss.val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
            FROM split_string(ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries, ',') ss(val)
           ) ss
     ) ss
WHERE ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID = 7493 AND
      ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue = 'all months' AND
      ERSBusinessLogic_Type = 'HS10 aggregation';
```